# Having trouble positioning an element in the lower left hand corner

Tags: html, css

This is supposed to be a twitter feed I am building, the class src-twitter is basically a timestamp and username of the poster, It should be on the lower right hand corner of the

, but in the result is is right in the middle of the quote.

```
<div class="feed-bottom">
                <div class="post1">
                    <p>
                        "You have brains in your head. You have feet in your shoes. You can steer yourself in any direction you choose. You're on your own, and you know what you know. And you are the guy who'll decide where to go." - Dr. Suess
                    </p>
                    <p class="src-twitter">
                        @username 5:55pm September 20, 2014
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
   .post1{
        position: relative;
    }

    .src-twitter {
        color:#dfdfdf;
        font-size: 12px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems no need to use `position` for this, just `text-align` do the trick

Updated CSS:

```
.src-twitter {
    color:#dfdfdf;
    font-size: 12px;        
    text-align:right;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/atpmLwz0/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwta0t8n/1/). The timestamp now appears at the bottom-right corner of the tweet. This is the new CSS which I've added:

```
.src-twitter {
        color:#dfdfdf;
        font-size: 12px;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mofeenster/xfpme4ze/) that still makes use of absolute positioning.

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}   
.post1{
    position: relative;
    padding: 16px;
}
.src-twitter {
    color:#dfdfdf;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -16px;
    right: 16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="feed-bottom">
 <div class="post1">
  <p>"You have brains in your head. You have feet in your shoes. You can steer yourself in any direction you choose. You're on your own, and you know what you know. And you are the guy who'll decide where to go." - Dr. Suess</p>
  <p class="src-twitter">@username 5:55pm September 20, 2014</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have added a simple reset to the HTML so you can have more control over margin & padding, as this will also affect the position (alignment) of your elements. I then add the padding back and then use the same units to position the author name with a negative bottom (you didn't do this that's one reason why it was in the middle of the main paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="feed-bottom">
                <div class="post1">
                    <p>
                        "You have brains in your head. You have feet in your shoes. You can steer yourself in any direction you choose. You're on your own, and you know what you know. And you are the guy who'll decide where to go." - Dr. Suess
                    </p>
                    <p> &nbsp; </p>
                    <p class="src-twitter">
                        @username 5:55pm September 20, 2014
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Position absolute does not expand the height of post1 ... easy solution is to add a empty space. Alternatively you can specify the height for post1.

Comment: Morgan's, method of providing a space is a little cleaner, padding:16px

Comment: Cheers Wayne, FYI: adding a set height is not a good idea in the day and age of responsive web design ;) Keep things fluid.

Comment: @MorganFeeney stressing the problem is because there is no height available was not intended to endorse setting height as a fix all. It is only suited when the height is fixed because of a graphic or something with a fixed height. My tendency is more to use design, IE a div with a background. Two important tags for semantic html IMHO are wrapper and a background tag.